# a4j:param not invoking my javascript pointed to by value attribute

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, param, ajax4jsf

I am open to a different way to do this, but what I have seems like it should work from the documentation for RichFaces4 and JSF2.

The user flow is like this:

- 1) There is a 'Check Out' document link implemented with h:outputLink
- 2) The user clicks it and gets prompted with a dialog to enter check out comments implemented with rich:popupPanel
- 3) The user enters comments and clicks 'Continue' Button on the rich:popupPanel implemented with h:link (tried h:commandLink and a4j:commandLink also)
- 4) A new window pops up with the contents set to the h:link outcome attribute

In my broken case, everything works except when I pass a parameter from h:link
with a4j:param, whose value attribute does not resolve the javascript it points to correctly.

```
<h:outputLink id="promptForCommentsLink"
              onclick="#{rich:component('commentsDlg')}.show();return false;"
              value="#"> Check Out </h:outputLink>

<rich:popupPanel id="commentsDlg" modal="true">
    <h:inputTextarea id="commentsId"/>
    <h:link id="continueLink"
              outcome="editorPage" <!-- editor for making changes to document -->
              target="_blank" <!-- open in it;s own indow -->
              value="Continue Check Out"
              onclick="#{rich:component('commentsDlg')}.hide();">

        <!-- these params get assignd to backing bean properties -->
        <a4j:param name="dataId"
                   value="#{ithRow.id}" assignTo="#{myController.dataId}"/>
        <a4j:param name="checkedOut"
                   value="true" assignTo="#{myController.checkedOut}"/>

        <!-- this one is broken. assigns chars 'document.getElementById('.. 
             to #{myController.checkOutComment} -->
        <a4j:param name="checkOutComment"
                   assignTo="#{myController.checkOutComment}"
                   noEscape="true"
value="document.getElementById('myForm:dataTable:0:commentsId').value"
                   />
    </h:link>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

I was thinking maybe

```
document.getElementById('myForm:dataTable:0:commentsId').value
```

didn't point to what I typed into the textarea, but by putting another button on the dlg and pointing it's onclick to the same element id, it did indeed alert me with what it typed.

When I stop on the server side view scoped myController.setCheckOutComment(String s) method, it gets passed the string "document.getElementById('myForm:dataTable:0:commentsId').value"

According to RF4 documentation:

*The a4j:param tag can be used with non-Ajax components in addition to Ajax components. This includes components which are working through the GET request, such as the h:link*

and

*Variables from JavaScript functions can be used for the value attribute. In such an implementation, the noEscape attribute should be set to true. Using noEscape="true", the value attribute can contain any JavaScript expression or JavaScript function invocation, and the result will be sent to the server as the value attribute.*

Since I seem to be playing by the jsf/rf4 rules, I thought this would be okay.

One thing to note, if I use a4j:commandLink instead of h:link, it does indeed
send the result of javascript evaluated, however, that breaks the opening in its own window
and a few other issues.

Any thoughts on what might be happening, or even a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a a4j:jsFunction with the parameters you need. Then call that function from the onclick in the h:link tag like setParams(#{ithRow.id}, true). Problem remain that you can't pass the value as a parameter to the javascript function. You could though use 'execute' to save the value of the inputArea to a backing bean and let the backend handle the value.

So yes, I would do it differently. I think you could handle the two other params at the backend and I would use 'execute' to store the value of the inputArea.

MAG,
Milo van der Zee

Comment: I had to go with a dif appoach to solving the issue describe,  because richfaces 4's a4j:param does not seem to be working with h:link as the documentation describes. a4j:param's value attribute is supposed to evalulate it as if it was javascript, if the noEscape=true attribute is provided. I will leave it open for someone else to answer, but the folks over at RF community never responded also. What i did was break the checking out process and editing into 2 mouse clicks/steps. one click updates DB indicating check out, user must then click again on h:link to open target content in new window.